# c# wpf Изменение картинки при выборе определеного значения в ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно сделать чтобы при выборе определеного значения в ComboBox проходило измениние картинки в Image, возможно ли реализовать?

Comment: Да, такое сделать возможно.

Comment: Ага, используйте привязку к SelectedItem комбобокса и конвертер

Comment: Такой вопрос уже задавали, надо поискать чтобы отметить дубликатом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать разными способами (с учетом использования или не использования конвертеров, MVVM, команд, привязок). Вот вам вариант, на мой взгляд самый простой и быстро реализуемый. (Будут минусовать :), ну и пусть)

1) Создайте папку в проекте и разместите туда файлы изображений

[image: вид на проект]

2) у каждого файла изображения сделайте след. свойства

[image: вид на свойства файла изображения]

3) важные для нас свойства комбобокса

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxSelectImage"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ListImages}"
              SelectionChanged="comboBoxSelectImage_SelectionChanged"
```

4) важные для нас свойства Image

```
<Image x:Name="imageOutput"
```

5) ну и кодбихайнд

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<string> _pathImages;
    public List<string> ListImages { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _pathImages = GetPathImages();
        ListImages = GetListImages();

        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Загрузка путей ко всем файлам в папке Images
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private List<string> GetPathImages()
    {
        string pathDir = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Images");

        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        foreach (var pathFile in Directory.GetFiles(pathDir))
        {
            result.Add(pathFile);
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Извлечение имен файлов из путей
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private List<string> GetListImages()
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        foreach (var path in _pathImages)
        {
            result.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path));
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Обработка события выбора в ComboBox (загрузка нужного изображения)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void comboBoxSelectImage_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var fileImage = _pathImages.FirstOrDefault(p =>
                                    p.Contains(this.comboBoxSelectImage.SelectedItem.ToString()));

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileImage)) return;

        BitmapImage imageSource = new BitmapImage();
        imageSource.BeginInit();
        imageSource.UriSource = new Uri(fileImage);
        imageSource.EndInit();

        this.imageOutput.Source = imageSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Показывет ошибку:
'GetPathImages' в не-делегатский тип 'List <string>'. 
 так же и GetListImages. 
Как это исправить?

Comment: Если вы точно все скопировали должно работать. Что еще за "не-делегатский тип"?

Comment: @Vadim здесь [можно скачать](https://yadi.sk/d/h5gVgMwL3PP2JG) проект целиком.

Comment: Спасибо, не-делегатский возможно трудности перевода Cannot convert method group 'GetPathImages' to non-delegate type 'List<string>'. 
перезагрузил проектвсе отлично)